# Scraping through multiple websites

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to get multiple tables and later transform it (after some manipulation) into one dataframe in R

#### see code below

```
countries <- c("au","at","de","se","gb","us")

for (i in countries) {
sides<-glue("https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/top-rated/",i,.sep = "") 
html[i] <- read_html(sides)
cont[i] <- html[i] %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()
}
```

If I do so, I get the following error message:

```
 *number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthError in 
 UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
   no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class 
 "list"*
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I tried it in another way (see below): with ```test <- lapply(glue("https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/top-rated/",i,.sep = ""), function(url){
  url %>% read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table()
}) ``` - Which however only gives me the first table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(tidyverse)
require(rvest)

path_base <- "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/top-rated/"
countries <- c("au","at","de","se","gb","us")

path <- paste0(path_base, countries)

html_files <- path %>% 
  map(read_html)

html_files %>% 
  map(html_node, css = "table") %>% 
  map(html_table, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```